# How is Spring able to notify about when an instance is destroyed?

Tags: java, spring

I am reading the Pro Spring 2.5 book and in chapter 4 they talk about life cycle callbacks. How is Spring able to notify when an instance is destroyed (after what I read it is only available on singletons)? What mechanism is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No magic here, destroy callbacks are called when the `BeanFactory`/`ApplicationContext` is destroyed (`close()` method is called). In desktop applications this has to be done manually, in servlet environment the same mechanism that was used to start the application context (typically [`ContextLoaderListener`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html)) handled destroying for you.

Two notes:

- destroying is important for objects requiring explicit clean-up like database connection pools (`DataSource`) or threads.
- Beans are destroyed in the opposite order compared to creation order. This is understandable: when bean `A` depends on `B`, `B` has to be created first. When bean `A` is destroyed, `B` has to be destroyed afterwards, otherwise `A` would not be able to access its dependencies during destroy phase.

Also Spring allows you to automatically register [shutdown hook](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html#registerShutdownHook%28%29) to handle shutdown automatically. I wouldn't advice that, but just for the record:

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(...)
ctx.registerShutdownHook();
```

Comment: Ah, so if you don't call close on the BeanFactory/ApplicationContext this would not cause the event to be triggered?

Comment: @Viper nope, as I said, no magic here. You must explicitly close the application context if it was explicitly created by you. Also Spring does not call destroy  life-cycle callbacks for `prototype` scoped beans - because it does not keep track of them after creating and initializing

Comment: I think you misunderstood the comment, that was what I said: If you don't close it won't call destroy life cycle callbacks. Anyway thank you :)

Comment: @Viper: maybe you're right, so to be clear: no, Spring will not destroy the beans if not asked to be destroy itself.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your environment, if you're running in a webapp, Spring is "finalized" once your servlet context is destroyed, so it can tell all of it's objects they are going to be destroyed.

BTW, **Pro Spring 2.5** is really old, you should probably grab a newer book, as there is a lot of stuff that changed between 2.5 and the 3.x series.